# how to show image that are stored above Document_Root

Tags: php, html, image

I set the src attribute of img the way below but was not working :

src="/../files/filenamee"

the image is not shown.

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to do this? Because this is almost unanimously seen as bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to reference images above `DocumentRoot` by any means. The URLs are interpreted by the Web browser, so it'll just request `/files/filename`. You'd need either to write a script which reads files from the desired directory and writes them to the user (a **bad idea**, because these scripts almost always open up an inadvertent security hole) or create a symbolic link to the directory from within your document root.

Comment: can u make a demo on how to write files above root directory to the user?